# Redirect back after login django-registration-redux

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am using django-registration-redux and i have a login form in my navbar. I would like to stay on the same page after login. ie. if i am at mypage.com/polls/example after login i want to be back on mypage.com/polls/example not on url set in settings.

Login from in html looks like this:

```
{% url "auth_login" as login_url %}
{% if login_url not in request.get_full_path %}
    <li>
        <form class="navbar-form" method="POST" action={{ login_url }}>{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control top-bar" name="username" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="password" class="form-control top-bar" name="password" placeholder={% trans "password" %} />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{% trans "Login" %}</button>
        </form>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *next* :

```
<form class="navbar-form" method="POST" action="{{ login_url }}?next={{request.path}}">
```

This will add a GET request to your form that points back to the current page.

For **request.path** to work you have to define template context processors in your **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```