# Redirect to Next after login in Django

Tags: django, authentication

When a user accesses a url which requires login. The view decorator redirects to the login page. after the user enters his username and password how can I redirect the user to the page he was trying to access ('next') ?

#### Views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    template = 'pos/login.html'
    form = LoginForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You have logged in!")
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, "Your account is disabled!")
                return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "The username or password are not valid!")
            return redirect('/login')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)

@login_required(redirect_field_name='next', login_url='/login')
def bar(request):
    template = 'pos/bar.html'
    drink = OrderItem.objects.filter(product__catgory__gt=1).order_by('-created')
    context = {'drink': drink}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

#### Login.html

```
<form action="/login" id="login_form" method="post" class="form-signin">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="login">Sign in</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
</form>
```

#### url.py

```
     url(r'^login', views.login_view, name='login'),
```

#### forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", required=True, max_length=30,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", required=True, max_length=30,
                           widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                               'class': 'form-control',
                               'name': 'password'}))
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100231/6522072). Add next to your action `<form action="/login?next={{request.path}}" id="login_form" method="post" class="form-signin"> `.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try:

```
return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))
```

Comment: I believe this would work but what if i need 'next' or 'home' ?

Comment: return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next', 'home') if 'home' is a named url. Otherwise it would be return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next', '/home/')

Comment: This works great. However it allows for redirecting to external urls. For many sites that would be a security problem.

Comment: Yes, this is called an open redirect and it is considered a security vulnerability by many.

Comment: this  code working thank you

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer does not check for the next parameter redirecting to an external site. For many applications that would be a security issue. Django has that functionality inbuilt in form of the `django.utils.http.is_safe_url` function. It can be used like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.http import url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme
from django.conf import settings

def redirect_after_login(request):
    nxt = request.GET.get("next", None)
    if nxt is None:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    elif not url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(
            url=nxt,
            allowed_hosts={request.get_host()},
            require_https=request.is_secure()):
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    else:
        return redirect(nxt)

def my_login_view(request):
    # TODO: Check if its ok to login.
    # Then either safely redirect og go to default startpage.
    return redirect_after_login(request)
```

Comment: This is still not safe. `is_safe_url` has [been renamed in Django 3 (see last bullet)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#id3). On top of using the new function, `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme`, you should also be sure to encode your URL with the `urlencode` filter.

Comment: @mlissner Thank you so much for that information, security is hard! Do you know the difference between `iri_to_uri` and `urlencode`?

Comment: I don't, though I raised this with the Django security folks and they recommended the iri_to_uri approach. We're using urlencode though, since I believe it accomplishes the same.

Comment: @mlissner I see. It looks as though the approach `contrib.auth` takes is to use `resolve_url` first on the raw value. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.7/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L131

Comment: `resolve_url` that doesn't accomplish any sanitation if you look at it in `django.shortcuts`. That approach seems problematic to me.

Comment: I dug into this a bit in a little POC. Because django.auth only does 302 redirects, it looks sufficiently safe to me (I don't *think* you can redirect to javascript, for example). But if you were to display the redirect_to parameter in your HTML, you'd be at risk.

Comment: @mlissner Would love to see the POC!

Comment: Well, it didn't actually "prove" anything, so I didn't post it. Just imagine a small Django app that uses the auth login.

Answer (score 3):

You can try by simply add this input field before submit button in accounts/login.html template

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Arun Ghosh option is better but it leads to an exception in cases where there is no next value is found.

Hence I used this approach.

`try: return redirect(request.GET.get('next')) except TypeError: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("default_app:url_name"))`

OR

`except Exception as e: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("default_app:url_name"))`

Answer (score 0):

This actually works for me quite nice:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    nxt = request.GET.get("next", None)
    url = '/admin/login/'

    if nxt is not None:
        url += '?next=' + nxt

return redirect(url)
```

If previous URL contained next - call "login" URL and append the previous "next" to it.
Then, when you logged in - you'll continue with the page that was previously intended to  be next.

In my project I made the following helper which works for Swagger login/logout:

```
def _redirect(request, url):
    nxt = request.GET.get("next", None)
    if nxt is not None:
        url += '?next=' + nxt
    return redirect(url)


def login(request):
    return _redirect(request, '/admin/login/')


def logout(request):
    return _redirect(request, '/admin/logout/')
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
path_redirect = request.get_full_path().split('?next=',1)
if '?next=' in request.get_full_path():# Redirecting After Login 
    return redirect(path_redirect[1])
else:
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: `https://example.com/?next=/some_page&some_other_parameter=1`
would redirect to
`https://example.com/some_page&some_other_parameter=1`
which is broken.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.