# Django - after login, redirect user to the page he/she was on

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I am currently working on a Django application and I am currently have an issue. The issue is that when the user is not logged in, and on the blog post page(In this case "post_detail") and hit the like button, the user is directed to the login page. However, once the user is signed in, the user is redirected back to the home page(In this case "blog_home" which shows a list view of all the blog posts).

Now, that is not what I wanted. I wanted the user to go back to the blog post page("post_detail" page).

After researching the problem, I realized it had to do with the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. However, after trying to fix the issue, I am having a hard time to redirect the user to the specific page.

Is there any ideas on how I can make it work? Any input is truly appreciated.

Settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/redirect'
```

views.py(blog):

```
def wherenext(request):
   if request.user:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail'))
   else:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_home'))
...
@login_required(redirect_field_name="post")
def LikeView(request, pk):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
   liked = False
   if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
       post.likes.remove(request.user)
       liked = False
   else:
       post.likes.add(request.user)
       liked = True
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
...
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
   ...
   
   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(BlogDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       stuff =get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
       total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
       liked = False
       if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
           liked = True

       context["liked"] = liked
       return context
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('redirect/', wherenext, name='post_detail'),
path('post/<uuid:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('',BlogListView.as_view(),name='blog_home'),
]
```

post_detail.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}"method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   {% if liked %}
   <button type="submit", name="post_id", value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</button> 
   {% else %}
   <button type="submit", name="post_id", value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button> 
                        
   {% endif %}
{% else %}
      {% if liked %}
         <button type="submit", name="post_id", value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</button> 
      {% else %}
         <button type="submit", name="post_id", value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button> 
                        
      {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: can you add redirect URL in your login page, like this -  /login?continue=ORIGINAL_URL ?

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431166/redirect-to-next-after-login-in-django

Comment: @cwlau, I tried adding the redirect URL in the login page, but I get an error: 127.0.0.1:8000/login?next=/accounts/login/

Answer (score 1):

If one is using the standard django auth framework, The login form html template should include the `next` form field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

The default LoginView will use `next` as its redirect success url.

django-allauth allows a custom success parameter.

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
```

to redirect to the current page, something like this:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next=request.get_full_path %}">Google</a>
```

Comment: isn't there a security issue with using <input type="hidden">? As of right now, I was not able to get this to work.

Comment: That form input is fine, there is nothing insecure about it.
The django documentation has it in the example code to achieve the next url.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/

Comment: I added the <input type="hidden">, and it still does not work.

Comment: The default django auth framework allows for the next param, eg. `/login/?next=/post/UUID/` .   Does adding that next param to the URL string work?

Comment: would I add this in the login.html form tag(action="/login/?next=/post/UUID/)? I tested this out and it did not work as well.  I am assuming I added the URL string in the wrong place.

Comment: If the next parameter does not work, you’ll have to look at the login view method or class.  The default Django does use the next parameter, but in this case you might be using a different auth method.

Comment: this is the error I am getting on the terminal: Not Found: /login/

Comment: I am using the django allauth.

Comment: What is the path to your login view? Try appending the ?next=/post/UUID to wherever the login url is.

Comment: django-allauth apparently allows for a next url in the login tag. 

From the docs: `<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>` .