# Django @login_required doesn't work when login function has redirect

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

In login view I have:

```
def login(request):
    ...
    login(request, user)
    messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged in to your account.')
    return redirect('user_app:profile')
```

In some other function I have `@login_required(login_url='/login/')` but their redirect doesn't work and allways redirect to `user_app:profile`.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/') #redirect to profile page instead of jobs page
def jobs(request):
    ...

@login_required(login_url='/login/') #redirect to profile page instead of offers page
def offers(request):
    ...
```

How do I redirect a user to page he/she redirected from it to login page, and redirect to the profile page **only** when he/she referred directly to the login page?

Comment: did you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061358/14457833

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to Next after login in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431166/redirect-to-next-after-login-in-django)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat In that question it always redirects to certain page `(next)`. It can comes from many pages.

Comment: `next` is not _fixed_ it is a querystring / GET parameter. If you look carefully when you get redirected to the login page due to the `login_required` decorator there should be a `next=<some_path>` in your url... In fact if you used the builtin [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) that is what it does.