# redirect to detail view after registration in django templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-authentication

I have a simple Group model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
   leader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
   description = models.TextField()
   joined = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

With a simple GroupDetail template:

```
<div>Leader: {{group.leader}}</div>
<div>Name: {{group.name}}</div>
<div>Description: {{group.description}}</div>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form action="{% url 'join_group' group.pk %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit" name="group_id" value="{{group.id}}">JOIN</button>  
  </form>
{% else %}
  <div><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a> to join chaburah</div>
{% endif %}
```

This works for when a User exists and just needs to sign in, but when a User registers, this method doesn't work, but I don't understand why. The `next` is being added in the url:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/register/?next=/group/83/
```

So, after registration, shouldn't the User be redirected? I'm assuming the issue is coming from my return here:

```
class UserRegistration(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        form.registration_notification()
        login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        return
```

Right now there's no value there because anything I put there would either throw an error or redirect to the wrong page. My question is what do I need to return in order for `next` to work for registration like it does for log in?

Comment: can you shaew your urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that worked from a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431166/redirect-to-next-after-login-in-django) talking about redirecting after logging in. But the logic ended up being the same. I added a `next` to my registration link and returned a redirect to that url:

```
<a href="{% url 'registration' %}?next={{request.path}}">
```

and in my views:

```
class UserRegistration(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        form.registration_notification()
        login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Django` natively supports `redirecting` to the given page. In practice, if the user gives an address to which he has no access, he will have to `log in`. After logging in, he will be redirected to the page he tried to access.

I think you can specify the page access from the model or view function, while in the template you can render the form.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class UserRegistration(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_authenticated
```

Also, [`success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) is called after it has been properly processed.

Comment: But a User is allowed to see every page even when they aren't authenticated, they just can't join a Group until they sign in or register. For log in I'm using the `?next={{request.path}}` but for register it's not working. After someone registers it's not passing any test because they didn't technically have to authenticate to view the GroupDetail. Just to join it.