# @login_required() next parameter has a backslash and is causing the url to not be found

Tags: python, html, css, django, cs50

When a non logged-in user attempts to create a listing, when he clicks the create listing link, he will be redirected to the login page before being able to create the listing.
The redirection to login page works, but after logging in successfully, it receives a `NoReverseMatch` error. [image]

[image]
When I print the next parameter, I get `'/create'`, but my create url is `'create'` only, so this is the reason why I'm having this error. Why does it have a backslash at the url? I can create a code to remove the backslash, but is there a better way to do it?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("listing/<int:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
    path("create",views.create, name="create"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            next_url = request.POST.get('next')
            print(next_url)
            if next_url and next_url !='/login':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(next_url))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        print(request.GET.get('next'))
        return render(request, "auctions/login.html")
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <h2>Login</h2>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to Next after login in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431166/redirect-to-next-after-login-in-django)

Comment: Your url patterns shows your app combines multiple functionalities. It is recommended that a django app should perform a specific task. So you should have one app for users or accounts, and another for listing. You are possibly getting this error because there's no separation of functionality in your django project. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: @journpy although it can be good to create separate apps according to functionalities that is not at all related to their error here. `next` is basically supposed to be a URL to redirect to, OP is passing it to `reverse` in their code which is wrong, it should directly be used as the redirect url similar to what is done in answers in the question I linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to remove the '/' in request.POST.get('next'). request.POST.get('next') is giving me '/create' which Django doesn't recognize, it only recognizes 'create'.
So I just do a string splice [1:] to remove the backslash, and everything works fine.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            next_url = request.POST.get('next')
            if next_url and next_url !='/login':
                modified_next_url = next_url[1:]
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(modified_next_url))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        print(request.GET.get('next'))
        return render(request, "auctions/login.html")


@login_required(login_url='login')
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': #if user submitted the form
        form = CreateListingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Saves the form data into a new 'Listing' object without committing it to database yet, allowing for further modifications
            listing = form.save(commit = False)
            #sets the owner field of the listing to currently logged in user 
            listing.owner = request.user
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = CreateListingForm()
    return render(request,"auctions/create.html",{
        "form": form,
    })
```

Comment: No, you just have to skip calling `reverse`, `HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)` is **exactly** what you want to run. The `next` parameter is not a URL name, it **is a URL**.